# How do I create a file listener in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, listener

I am trying to create a listener on a specific directory that kicks off a Linux command whenever a file shows up in this path. For example, whenever a file shows up in a directory like C:/home/ I would like to read a string of text from that file and then kick off another command. I was thinking of using a loop but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Linux doesn't have 'C:' as a drive.  I am confused.

Comment: If you don't have to know immediately, you can sleep for a period of time, instead of polling it constantly. You can still use a loop, but do it once a minute (or perhaps longer).

Comment: @squiguy you're right, my bad. I meant /home/ or something like that. Brain fart from switching between OSs too much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get notified about events like file creation, opening, modifying etc. look into [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). A good way to use it from bash is with the `inotifywait` command - [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) is its man page. It will block until an event you care about happens. For example:

```
inotifywait -e create /path/to/watch
echo "ding!"
```

will ding when a file or directory gets created in that path. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) for more details.